# Set CSS @Media min-width value with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 3.0 for my website and i use @media queries in CSS to create a responsive design. I would like to add a button that allows someone on a phone to view the site as they would see it on a larger desktop screen.

Is there a way i can force CSS to think that the max-width/min-width is a certain size? I don't want to actually show scrollbars, just change what rules are applied to match what would be shown for larger screen sizes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could manipulate the meta viewport tag to use a specific pixel dimension, an example with jQuery would look like:

```
$('meta[name="viewport"]').attr("content", "width=1280")
```

If you wanted the screen to render 1280 pixels into the viewable area.

Answer (score 0):

You will follow these steps

1)add this meta tag to your **html** page **inside** of **head tag**

`<meta name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width; initial-scale=0.95;" />`

2)in css file for every .class you can do this one

```
    @media(max-width:1280px){
       .abc{ width:100%;}
    }
```

try to these steps. You can solve your problem